# Абстрактное синтаксическое дерево

Tags: php, парсер

Необходимо по исходному коду на [Hack](http://hacklang.org/) построить синтаксическое дерево. Может быть, уже есть готовые библиотеки или программы? Если нет, то как проще это сделать?

Мои идеи: провести лексический анализ, получив на выходе токены, а затем применить синтаксический анализ для построения самого дерева. С синтаксическим вроде всё понятно, а вот с лексическим основная проблема - это составить грамматику для языка Hack (HHVM).

Comment: а исходный код на чем?

Comment: На HackLang (язык сделаный фэйсбуком)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/download.html)

Отлично строит дерево, удобный API, работает с несколькими популярными языками программирования(Java, C#, Python 2/3, JavaScript, Go, C++, Swift).